# How frequently is the list of constituents that make up the S&P/ASX 300 updated?

Tags: stocks, australia, market-indexes

How frequently is the list of constituents that make up the [S&P/ASX 300](http://au.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-asx-300) updated?

Is it once a month on the 1st Monday of the month, or daily, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The S&P/ASX 300 is rebalanced every six months, with changes taking
>   effect on the third Friday of March and September.

From a PDF under [Methodology](http://www.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-asx-300)